# How to implement GCM CCS(XMPP) server on app engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am Developing CCS server using XMPP,I followed all steps given on the [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) website.This code(using java smack library) runs perfectly,as I am getting notification on my android mobile app.I have CCS service enabled on my App Engine Project.But when I tried to deploy it on  App engine I am getting.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFound Exception for
>   org/jivesoftware/Smack/XMPPException !!!!!!

after going through some websites (including this also)and [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) site I found that

> Note that Google App Engine does not support connections to CCS

My question is:

1>>.App Engine doesn't support java smack library or it don't support connection to ccs(xmpp)end point at all?

google has also provided [XMPP service to App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp)

2>>.Is it possible to implement GCM CCS(XMPP) server using googles XMPP library?If it is possible please give some reference or tutorial.

I can really use some help with this questions,because I am so confused what do next!!!

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that GAE does not support connections to CCS. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

Comment: Looks like it does: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp. GAE seems to support XMPP, but I guess you won't be able to use it with GCM, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp) gives a hint that it is possible. Also have a look into [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127541/gcm-and-app-engine-for-chat-application).