# GCM and App Engine for chat application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to make a chat app through which user can send and receive text and media - audio, image and video. For simplicity I decided to use app engine with GCM. Doing downstream with GCM seems to be working well (for text messages) using the example guide provided and Android Studio template. When I tried upstream I did not receive the message back. May be this is very trivial but can someone please point me to a good tutorial or book on this. Any suggestions?

Used this for downstream: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints 
And this for upstream: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream

Comment: You can use Xmpp/openfire fire chat application i have already developed the chat apllication and it si working fine........@user531069

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to have app-engine only as my backend server.

Comment: try this demo for more help you : http://www.grokkingandroid.com/upstream_messages_with_google_cloud_messaging/ and 
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/google-cloud-messaging-cloud-connection-server-tutorial

Comment: Hey user531069, thank you for doing that approach. What can you say about the performance about GCM + CCS + AppEngine? How long does it take for a message to be delivered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add 
@ApiMethod(name = "sendMessage")
to sendMessage method in MessagingEndpoint class generated through Studio template. After that I was able to use the sendMessage api to send the message back to app engine server which is linked to GCM and that message echoed back to my device as well.